# QT application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized on WSL2

Tags: qt, ubuntu, wsl-2

I followed [this guide](https://developernote.com/2022/10/building-qt6-4-on-ubuntu-22-04/) and built QT6.5.1 on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 with the following configuration:

```
${QT_SRC_PATH}/configure -prefix $MY_INSTALL_PATH -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS=1 -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -opensource -confirm-license \
  -c++std c++20 -static -static-runtime -openssl-linked
```

Then I built an app with my QT and tried to run it I got this:

```
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3" since plugins are disabled in static builds
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I run `ldd` just in case:

```
$ ldd ./TradeClient
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc2233d000)
libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007faf00535000)
libdrm.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007faf0051f000)
libOpenGL.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0 (0x00007faf004f3000)
libEGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007faf004e0000)
libmd4c.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd4c.so.0 (0x00007faf004ce000)
libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007faf00428000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007faf001fe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007faf00117000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faf000f7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faeffecf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faf04266000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007faeffe17000)
```

also I tried

```
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=~/libs/QT6.5/plugins
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1

$ xhost +local:
non-network local connections being added to access control list
```

but this all did not help.